# GPG - remove header from decrypted text

Tags: linux, command-line, gpg

I  want to get rid of two first lines generated after the usage of `gpg -d file.txt.gpg`, meaning that only text itself would be left. I tied to use `--no-comment`, but it seems to not work.

```
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID 4FXXXXXXXXD30D52, created 2020-01-22
      "test test <test@test.test>"
test
test444
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gpg --quiet -d file.txt.gpg
```

(or `-q`)

Answer (score 0):

In order to skip the first two lines of the output of a command, you can pipe it through `awk` and instruct it to ignore the first two lines:

```
~$ <whatever command> | awk 'NR<3 {next} {print}'
```

This will instruct `awk` to skip execution (`next`) of the line as long as `awk`'s internal line counter (`NR`) is smaller than 3, but otherwise `print` the whole input line unchanged.

**Edit**

Note that since these two first lines seem to be written to `stderr` instead of `stdout` (as per @dave_thompson_085's comment), it is easier to either use @Anonymous' solution with the `-q` flag, or simply redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` or an error file, as in

```
gpg -d file.txt.gpg 2>error.log
```

Comment: gpg writes those two lines to stderr not stdout, so this doesn't work unless you use `2>&1 |` or on shells that support it `|&`